# Ошибка в доступах проекта

Tags: yii2

Вроде все работало но сейчас при загрузке любой страницы, в инструментах разработчика в браузере посмотрел, ошибка в этом запросе:

> `Request URL:http://mysite/favicon.ico`!

Что такое    `favicon.ico`  я не знаю и почему к нему идет запрос - тоже ! У меня такого в коде нет!

Результат ошибки :

> An Error occurred while handling another error:
>   yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException: You are not allowed to perform this
>   action. in
>   hosts/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php:151

В контролере прописал парамитры `access`!

**В чем может быть проблема в доступе ? Как ее решить ?**

Comment: Cоздать иконку (либо пустой файл) в корне сайта с название favicon.ico. Это даже может немного снизить нагрузку, так как не сработает перенаправление на index.php с поднятием фреймворка и обработкой роутинга и прочей логики а еще лучше закешить её в htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`favicon.ico` - значок веб-сайта или веб-страницы, который отображается браузером во вкладке перед названием страницы, а также в качестве картинки рядом с закладкой.

Можно браузеру указать явно, где находится эта иконка. Для явного указания местоположения `favicon.ico` необходимо вписать следующую строку в код страницы вашего сайта внутрь секции `head`, пример:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/someimage.png" />
```

Многие современные браузеры не требуют явного указания на `favicon.ico` в коде страницы. В случае отсутствия такого указания браузер пытается загрузить `favicon.ico`из корня сайта. Что, собственно, и пытается сделать браузер в вашем случае.